# Remove div tag with specific id and retain content

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement of removing a specific div tag with a unique id from the string and retain content. I want to strip out the div with a id="anchorWrap" as shown belove.

```
<div class="stl_ stl_02">
        <div class="stl_view">
            <div class="stl_05 stl_06">
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:18.0477em;top:1.7673em;"><span class="stl_15 stl_08 stl_16" style="word-spacing:0.1552em;"><div style="background:#bba61c; display: inline-block;" id="anchorWrap">Chief Complaint &nbsp;</div></span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:1.6em;top:17.4546em;"><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_18" style="word-spacing:0.0066em;">This is a 37 y.o. WM who presents with &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:1.6em;top:21.0546em;"><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_19" style="word-spacing:-0.0041em;">dysphagia of</span><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_14" style="word-spacing:0.1527em;">&nbsp;</span><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_09" style="word-spacing:-0.0028em;">solid foods for three years &nbsp;</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The expected result is

```
<div class="stl_ stl_02">
        <div class="stl_view">
            <div class="stl_05 stl_06">
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:18.0477em;top:1.7673em;"><span class="stl_15 stl_08 stl_16" style="word-spacing:0.1552em;">Chief Complaint &nbsp</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:1.6em;top:17.4546em;"><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_18" style="word-spacing:0.0066em;">This is a 37 y.o. WM who presents with &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:1.6em;top:21.0546em;"><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_19" style="word-spacing:-0.0041em;">dysphagia of</span><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_14" style="word-spacing:0.1527em;">&nbsp;</span><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_09" style="word-spacing:-0.0028em;">solid foods for three years &nbsp;</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried this regex

```
let anchorString = anchorText.replace(/<div id="anchorWrap">\s*(.*?)\s*<\/div>/gi, "");
```

But was not able to remove that div. Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are those in string or dom element?

Comment: you can easily do this using jquery. Just store the text value of this div and apply that content  to parent div.

Comment: @HWSiew those are in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('anchorWrap'); // get the element
var pe = el.parentNode; // get parent
while(el.firstChild) pe.insertBefore(el.firstChild, el); // insert content

pe.removeChild(el); // remove el
```

```html
<div class="stl_ stl_02">
  <div class="stl_view">
      <div class="stl_05 stl_06">
          <div class="stl_01" style="left:18.0477em;top:1.7673em;"><span class="stl_15 stl_08 stl_16" style="word-spacing:0.1552em;"><div style="background:#bba61c; display: inline-block;" id="anchorWrap">Chief Complaint &nbsp;</div></span></div>
          <div class="stl_01" style="left:1.6em;top:17.4546em;"><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_18" style="word-spacing:0.0066em;">This is a 37 y.o. WM who presents with &nbsp;</span></div>
          <div class="stl_01" style="left:1.6em;top:21.0546em;"><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_19" style="word-spacing:-0.0041em;">dysphagia of</span><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_14" style="word-spacing:0.1527em;">&nbsp;</span><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_09" style="word-spacing:-0.0028em;">solid foods for three years &nbsp;</span></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update: using `DOMParser()` for *htmlString*

```js
var elStr = `<div class="stl_ stl_02">
  <div class="stl_view">
      <div class="stl_05 stl_06">
          <div class="stl_01" style="left:18.0477em;top:1.7673em;"><span class="stl_15 stl_08 stl_16" style="word-spacing:0.1552em;"><div style="background:#bba61c; display: inline-block;" id="anchorWrap">Chief Complaint &nbsp;</div></span></div>
          <div class="stl_01" style="left:1.6em;top:17.4546em;"><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_18" style="word-spacing:0.0066em;">This is a 37 y.o. WM who presents with &nbsp;</span></div>
          <div class="stl_01" style="left:1.6em;top:21.0546em;"><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_19" style="word-spacing:-0.0041em;">dysphagia of</span><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_14" style="word-spacing:0.1527em;">&nbsp;</span><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_09" style="word-spacing:-0.0028em;">solid foods for three years &nbsp;</span></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>`;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(elStr, 'text/html');

var el = htmlDoc.getElementById('anchorWrap'); // get the element
var pe = el.parentNode; // get parent
while(el.firstChild) pe.insertBefore(el.firstChild, el); // insert content

pe.removeChild(el); // remove el
elStr = htmlDoc.querySelector("body").innerHTML
console.log(elStr);
```

Comment: This div and span tags are in a string. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: @Mithunreddy, please check the second solution in the updated answer:)

Answer (score 1):

Since the html is text, you could create a DOM-element, and set your string to be the innerHTML of that element.

Then, create a document fragment so that you can query the content which is inside the `anchorWrap`-element:

```js
const anchorText = `<div id="anchorWrap"><div class="stl_ stl_02">
        <div class="stl_view">
            <div class="stl_05 stl_06">
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:18.0477em;top:1.7673em;"><span class="stl_15 stl_08 stl_16" style="word-spacing:0.1552em;"><div style="background:#bba61c; display: inline-block;" id="anchorWrap">Chief Complaint &nbsp;</div></span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:1.6em;top:17.4546em;"><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_18" style="word-spacing:0.0066em;">This is a 37 y.o. WM who presents with &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:1.6em;top:21.0546em;"><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_19" style="word-spacing:-0.0041em;">dysphagia of</span><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_14" style="word-spacing:0.1527em;">&nbsp;</span><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_09" style="word-spacing:-0.0028em;">solid foods for three years &nbsp;</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>`; // html string

// create DOM element
var tmpEl = document.createElement('div');
// set the content of that element from our html text
tmpEl.innerHTML = anchorText;
// create document fragment
const fragmet = document.createDocumentFragment();
// add the created html-element into the fragment so we can run DOM-queries
fragmet.appendChild(tmpEl);
// query the element (now it is a HTMLElement, not a string)
const anchorWrapEl = fragmet.getElementById('anchorWrap');
// get all the content within the anchorWrap-element
const anchorWrapConent = anchorWrapEl.innerHTML;
console.log('here is our result', anchorWrapConent);
```

If you are able to run the code in a web browser, I think this should work. No need for complex regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to copy the content of the div with id="anchorWrap". Then you have to reach its immediate parent which is span. Then assign that copied value to span. The solution uses jquery.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="stl_ stl_02">
      <div class="stl_view">
        <div class="stl_05 stl_06">
          <div class="stl_01" style="left: 18.0477em; top: 1.7673em">
            <span class="stl_15 stl_08 stl_16" style="word-spacing: 0.1552em"
              ><div style="background: #bba61c; display: inline-block" id="anchorWrap">Chief Complaint &nbsp;</div></span
            >
          </div>
          <div class="stl_01" style="left: 1.6em; top: 17.4546em">
            <span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_18" style="word-spacing: 0.0066em">This is a 37 y.o. WM who presents with &nbsp;</span>
          </div>
          <div class="stl_01" style="left: 1.6em; top: 21.0546em">
            <span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_19" style="word-spacing: -0.0041em">dysphagia of</span><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_14" style="word-spacing: 0.1527em">&nbsp;</span
            ><span class="stl_17 stl_08 stl_09" style="word-spacing: -0.0028em">solid foods for three years &nbsp;</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Solution:

```
let divValue = $("#anchorWrap").text();
$("#anchorWrap").parent().get(0).innerHTML = divValue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let anchorText = document.getElementById("anchorWrap").innerText;
document.querySelector(".stl_15").innerHTML = anchorText;
```

this should solve it